# How to make an app return search results within itself for quick page navigation offline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, input, dreamweaver

I am building a multi-page mobile application that will be run offline but it needs to be able to search for pages within itself for users to navigate around the application easy. So far everything I see online for advice about this involves  or Jquery menu, and both to the best of my knowledge perform searches online with servers. What is the best advice for the element to use or direction to go for me to build a search bar where users enter a search and a list of items that are the available pages within the app appear so that the user can select on the results and navigate to those pages quickly? I am completely new and fumbling my way though this, I appreciate any help I can get

Comment: maybe an array of string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a json object like:

```
{
    pages: [
        'home': '/home',
        'options': '/options',
        'etc': '/etc'
    ]
}
```

and use that as your data for your search to return from. Not incredibly clean, but serves the purpose.

Comment: okay, so this is how I would store my pages, How would I call them via <input> search? like if a user typed in "home" in the <input> what would be the best way to set it up so the results display like a list underneath the <input> and the user can select them and be directed to their page?

Comment: I would use the search input to call a js function that does a regex based on what you've entered, then directs you to a page of the results. Or even better, pops a modal of the search results.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much, now I got a solid direction of where to focus my learning, I appreciate it!